# É possivel fazer uma comparação entre itens de duas listas e caso haja semelhança entre itens não exibir esse item em uma dataTable?

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee, lista

Tenho uma lista que é preenchida por dados de um arquivo xml e outra lista que é retornada de uma consulta no banco. 
Gostaria de saber se é possivel eu comparar um código existente nessas 2 listas. Se os códigos forem iguais não exibir esse elemento na dataTable.

**Exemplo:**

```
Lista 1 (xml): [processo[cod= 123, nome=Diego], processo[cod= 321, nome=Bruno]]
Lista 2 (bd):  [processo[cod=321, nome Bruno], processo[cod = 456, nome=josé]]
```

O processo de código `321` e nome `Bruno` existe nas duas listas, então ele não é exibido na `dataTable`

**DataTable:**

```
Código              Nome

123                 Diego
456                 José
```

Como faço para chegar a esse resultado?

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dtBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class SolicitacoesBean {
private List<Solicitacoes> list;
private List<Solicitacoes> listaFiltrada;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // pega a lista com os dados do .xml
                try {
                    list = XmlParserSolicitacoes
                            .realizaLeituraXML("C:\\Solicitacoes.xml");
                    System.out.println(list);

                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
}
```

Método que retorna a consulta do banco em uma list:

```
public List<SolicitacoesBD> listar(){
        SolicitacoesDAO dao = new SolicitacoesDAO();
        List<SolicitacoesBD>lista = dao.listar();

        for(SolicitacoesBD s : lista){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

Minha dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado" var="lista"
                value="#{dtBasicView.list}"
                filteredValue="#{dtBasicView.listaFiltrada}" rows="10"
                paginator="true" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                rowKey="#{lista.codigoBeneficiario}">

                <p:column headerText="Código" filterBy="#{lista.codigoBeneficiario}" style="width:20%" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.codigoBeneficiario}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nome" filterBy="#{lista.nomePessoa}" style="width:45%;"
                    sortBy="#{lista.nomePessoa}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.nomePessoa}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Senha" style="width:10%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.senha}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Data Solic." style="width:20%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.dataSolicitacao}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Status" style="width:22%" sortBy="#{lista.status}" filterBy="#{lista.status}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.status}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Opções" style="width:7%">
                    <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-search"
                        action="#{dtBasicView.abrirDialogo}" process="@this">
                        <!--                Mandar informação para outra página -->
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dtBasicView.solicitacoes}" value="#{lista}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Se você usar uma lista `Set` não vai remover os repetidos? ou tem atributos diferentes?

Comment: Tem atributos diferentes, devo deixar os atributos iguais?

Comment: Uma solução bem chula seria rodar 2 laços na lista e remover os valores repetidos.

Comment: Mas pra isso todos os elementos teriam que ser iguals? Ou posso comparar só o código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução bem ordinária seria

```
Iterator<Solicitacoes> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Solicitacoes solicitacao = iter.next();

    for(Solicitacoes s : lista){
        if (s.getCodigoBeneficiario() == solicitacao.getCodigoBeneficiario()) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está dando erro, `Iterator<SolicitacoesBD> iter = list.iterator();`

Comment: list é do tipo Solicitacoes

Comment: @Techies Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Só confere se é `getCodigoBeneficiario` mesmo

Comment: Não está entrando no if

Comment: Estou tentando arrumar

Comment: Pronto, arrumei e está funcionando perfeitamente. Só não entendi muito o código, por isso vou pesquisar um pouco sobre Iterator. Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria algo assim:

```
private List<Solicitacoes> listDB;
private List<Solicitacoes> listXML;
private List<Solicitacoes> listaFiltrada;

private void filtrar() {
  listDB = dao.listar();
  listXML = XmlParserSolicitacoes.realizaLeituraXML("C:\\Solicitacoes.xml");
  List<Solicitacoes> list = new ArrayList<Solicitacoes>(listDB.size() + listXML.size());
  list.addAll(listDB);
  list.addAll(listXML);
  listaFiltrada = new LinkedList<Solicitacoes>();
  for (Solicitacoes s : list) {
    if (!listDB.contains(s) || !listXML.contains(s)) {
      listaFiltrada.add(s);
    };
  };
};
```

Eu fiz meio de cabeça, mas a lógica está aí. Não é a forma mais eficiente mas é a forma mais fácil de ler que eu imaginei.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, obrigado